# JavaScript / CSS Image Scroller IE7 issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, scroller

I am tring to get an image gallery to scroll its thumbnails, rendering with css and javascript. It's working in all recent browsers, IE8, Firefox, Safari and Chrome, but will not render adequatly in IE7.

I've read a lot about overflow: hidden and IE7 which requires a position:relative in the container, but it doesn't seem to render my page the way it should.

The thumbnail container gets a fixed width assigned relatively to the number of thumbnails it contains. The scroller and all behave like it should, but IE will display the horizontal scrollbar on the page, even if childs are hidden.

I don't know what to do anymore to get this fixed.

http://www.photographiem.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=49&Itemid=59

Comment: overflow: does not require you to set positioning.
`<div style="width:10px; overflow:hidden;">xxxxxxxxxxxx</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was seeing all of your thumbs on hover of the button.

**Add** in vsig.css

```
div#vsig_thumbs_container {
    overflow:hidden;
```

**Remove** from `<head>`

`<!--[if IF 7]>width:auto;` // This is working against you. You need a fixed width on the container.

**Move** your inline CSS to your CSS file. Or, if PHP is producing that portion of your page, have it do so AFTER you JavaScript tags.

Comment: Thank you so much. Never though of adding this to the main thumb containers.

Comment: No problem. Please select the answer so the question will be closed.